# Find the default application for a certain extension

Tags: xdg-open

Given xdg-open and an extension, is there a way to get the application which xdg-open is set to for that particular extension?

For example given `xdg-open` and `.jpg` the result is `eog`.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: This is Ubuntu Trusty.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

AFAIK the choice of action is based on the file's mimetype rather than its extension.

At least on Ubuntu, you should be able to use the `query` action of `xdg-mime` to show the default application for a specific mimetype

```
$ xdg-mime query default image/jpeg
eog.desktop
```

You can check the mimetype for a particular file using `xdg-mime query filetype` e.g.

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype kqDRdnW.jpg
image/jpeg
```

or using the `file` command e.g. `file --mime-type <file>`

See `man xdg-mime` for further usage information.

Comment: probably worth mentioning to the OP that the way you get the mime-type for the filetype jpeg is `xdg-mime query filetype <file_you_want_the_mimetype_of>`

Comment: @the_velour_fog good point - added

Comment: Unfortunately `xdg-mime query default` doesn't always work if `xdg-open` just calls an underlying tool (eg `pcmanfm`); the example you used in your answer returns nothing on my LXDE system.

Comment: Thankyou, I would go first option here, `var="xdg-mime query default image/jpeg" && $(${var%.desktop})`

Answer (score 6):

**To query the mime type used by an existing file** by using `xdg-utils`, it works as:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype yourfile.xxx
```

You can also set a new default, for instance to change an associated desktop entry by setting **Thunar** - *a modern file manager for the Xfce Desktop Environment* - as the default file browser you should enter:

```
$ xdg-mime default Thunar.desktop inode/directory
```

Or for example to set the default application for `http(s)://` internet protocols, you can use:

```
$ xdg-mime default midori.desktop x-scheme-handler/http

OR

$ xdg-mime default midori.desktop x-scheme-handler/https
```

Comment: This isn't limited to `rpm` based systems; it's part of the standard desktop and works on Debian (for example).  Unfortunately this is how to _set_ a default value; it doesn't say how to _find_ what value is set.  And `xdg-mime query default` doesn't always report what it will do if `xdg-open` calls an underlying desktop program (eg `pcmanfm` on LXDE).

Comment: @StephenHarris I thought options might be different. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.